# passing an instance of a class to another class in order to use its variables

Tags: php, class, parameter-passing, instance-variables

I'm trying to pass an instance of my Generator class to another class to use some of the variables. The Generator class instance works fine but when i passed it to another (SelectStrategy) class it seems it is not passing the variable at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - I used var_dump on the called function to check what it gives me but it's just blank.

Function

```
class Generator 
{
    //properties for self
    private $s_charge;
    public $connection;
    public $task_priority;
    public $fog_mode = true;
    public $nodes = array();
    public $type;

    public function generateNodesSpecs() {
        $node = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {

            $charge1 = mt_rand(30,100);
            $node['charge'] = $charge1;
            //array_push($node, $charge1);
            $hops = mt_rand(0,4);
            $node['hops'] = $hops;
            //array_push($node, $hops);
            $resource1 = mt_rand(0,100);
            if ($resource1 <= 50) {
                if ($resource1 <=10){
                    $node['connection'] = '4G';
                    //array_push($node, '4G');
                }
                else {
                    $node['connection'] = '3G';
                    //array_push($node, '3G');
                }
            }
            else if ($resource1 > 50 && $resource1 <= 60) {
                $node['connection'] = 'WiFi';
                //array_push($node, 'WiFi');
            }
            else {
            }
            $resource2 = mt_rand(0,100);
            if ($resource2 <=60) {
                $node['additional'] = 'CPU';
                //array_push($node, 'CPU');
            }
            else {
            $node['additional'] = 'none';
            }
            $this->nodes[] = $node;
            //array_push($nodes, $node);
            unset($node);

        }
    //compare which get the resources
    //var_dump($this->nodes[0]); 
    }
class SelectStrategy {
//take in generator class instance
    private $generator;
    private $priority;
    private $size;
    private $slaves = array();
    private $found_slave = null; //will hold item with max val;
    public function __construct($generator) {
        $this->generator = $generator;
    }
private function selectSlaves() {
        $max = -9999999; //will hold max val
        foreach($this->generator->nodes as $k=>$v)
        {
            if($v['charge']>$max)
            {
               $max = $v['charge'];
               $this->found_slave = $v;
            }
        }

        var_dump($this->found_slave); 

} 
}
```

And classes/function calls

```
$generator = new Generator();
$generator->generateNodesSpecs();
$select_strategy = new SelectStrategy($generator);
$select_strategy->selectSlaves();
```

The `$this->generator->nodes` is a 2D array

Comment: please also post the `Generator` code.

Comment: The first issue i see is `$select_strategy = selectSlaves();` it should be `$select_strategy->selectSlaves();` On top of that the properties in your `Generator` instances would need to be public or otherwise accessible but we need you to post your `Generator` code to determine any issues there.

Comment: if `$nodes` is a private attribute, then your selectstrategy won't be able to access it. you'd be coming in from "outside" the generator object, and therefore private stuff will be invisible/inaccessible.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, the nodes are public and I corrected the mistake but still it doesn't show anything. I updated my post with generator class.

Comment: You have quite a few unquoted array keys in your `Generator`... for example: `$node[connection]` should be `$node['connection']` or `$node[$this->connection]` if its supposed to reference the instance member. But you have done this for `charge` and a few others as well.

Comment: True, I haven't noticed that. I corrected it and added all the quoted but still the var_dump doesn't show anything....

Comment: You have the private function.

Comment: Awesome, yeah that must have been the issue. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
global $generator;
```

in every function of SelectSlave should do it

Comment: you mean to just add that line to a selectSlaves function? or to edit every line that has a generator variable declared? I tried adding it to selectSlaves() function but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: private function selectSlaves() {
global $generator;//or w/e your class is declared as in your index file $xx= new Generator;.
and remove private $generator;
        $max = -9999999; //will hold max val
        foreach($this->generator->nodes as $k=>$v)
        {
            if($v['charge']>$max)
            {
               $max = $v['charge'];
               $this->found_slave = $v;
            }
        }

        var_dump($this->found_slave); 

}